# How to get public prime from DHE from TLS v1 DHE-RSA x.509 certificate?

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl, x.509

I can view the certificate using

> openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.masaood.com:443 </dev/null

I can view the public key of a RSA, but cannot find any information for DHE:

> openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.masaood.com:443  </dev/null | openssl x509 -pubkey -noout

How do I view the prime number and base g of the DHE protocol in the certificate with OpenSSL or any information of the DHE shared key exchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from Wireshark option, I found out it is possible to view the handshake protocol via [OpenSSL trace option](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:S_client(1)#OPTIONS)

> **Trace**: show verbose trace output of protocol messages. OpenSSL needs to be compiled with enable-ssl-trace for this option to work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with any openssl command line program. At most you might use `-debug` option with `openssl s_client` so that it shows you all the transferred data as hex and then you can try to figure out what this means. It is far easier to use Wireshark to sniff the connection and then look at all the handshake details. This gives you also the DH parameters you want to know:

[image]